# static_assert inside/outside class definition

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, static-assert

Why does static_assert need to be out side of the class definition?

**Failing code**

```
#include <type_traits>

class A
{
public:
    A(A&&) noexcept {}
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<A>::value, "ERROR");
};

int main()
{
}
```

**Working code**

```
#include <type_traits>

class A
{
public:
    A(A&&) noexcept {}

};

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<A>::value, "ERROR");

int main()
{
}
```

And when is it appropriate to use static_asserts in the definition of a class or struct?

Comment: What doesn't work about the first one? Is there an error message?

Comment: I have edited the question title to match the question contents.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The failing code give this message when compiled with g++ --std=c++11
{code} is_nothrow_move_constructible.cpp:8:1: error: static assertion failed: ERROR
 static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<A>::value, "ERROR");
{code}

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As far as the placement of `static_assert` itself is concerned both versions of your code are valid. So, no, `static_assert` does not need to be outside of class definition. Formally `static_assert` is a *declaration*. It is allowed wherever declarations are allowed.

The problem you are having has nothing to do with `static_assert` itself.

The problem here is that the expression that you use as the argument of your `static_assert` (`std::is_nothrow_move_constructible`) requires the class type to be *complete* to work properly. But inside the definition of class `A` class type `A` is not complete yet, which makes your argument expression invalid. This is why your `static_assert` works as intended only outside the class definition, where `A` is complete. However, this is entirely about proper usage of `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible`, not about `static_assert` itself.

Note, that inside member function bodies class type is seen in its entirety, as complete type, even if the member function is defined inside the class definition. Using this feature you can rewrite your code as

```
class A
{
public:
    A(A&&) noexcept {
      static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<A>::value, "ERROR"); 
    }
};
```

and `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<A>` will produce the proper result.

Comment: And, AFAIK, `static_assert` can *be used inside the body of a function*